# Modify default number of Elasticsearch shards

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have a 15 node cluster, do I have to change the

index.number_of_shards

value on all 15 nodes, and restart them, before the new value comes into effect for new indexes?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That is right changing `index.number_of_shards` defaults in config file  would involve changing the setting on all nodes  and then restarting the instance ideally following the guidelines for [rolling restarts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_rolling_restarts.html).

However if that is not an option and if explicitly specifying the `number_of_shards` in the settings while creating the new index is not ideal then the workaround would be  using [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html)

Example:

One can create an `index_defaults` default as below

```
PUT /_template/index_defaults 
{
  "template": "*", 
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 4
  }
}
```

This applies the setting specified in `index_defaults` template to all new indexes.

Comment: Restarting all nodes would be an option as it's a lot less painful w/ Elasticsearch 1.7, but I had forgotten about index templates.    That's the perfect solution in this case!  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Once you set the number of shards for an index in ElasticSearch, you cannot change them. You will need to create a new index with the desired number of shards, and depending on your use case, you may want then to transfer the data to the new index.

I say depending on the use case because, for instance, if you are storing time based data such as log events, it is perfectly reasonable to close one index and open a new one with a different number of shards, and index all data going forward to that new index, keeping the old one for searches.

However, if your use case is, for instance, storing blog documents, and your indices are by topic, then you will need to (a) create new indices as stated above with a different number of shards and (b) reindex your data. For (b) I recommend using the Scroll and Scan API to get the data out of the old index.

Comment: Thanks Mauricio.  I am looking to change for new indexes only.   Wondering if I need to start all nodes for the new default to come into effect.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a template for new indices that will be created:

```
PUT /_template/index_defaults 
{
    "index_patterns": "*", 
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 1,
            "number_of_replicas" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

For old indices you need to reindex.

Example: from my_old_index to my_new_index

Create the new index with appropriate mapping and settings:

```
PUT my_new_index
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 1,
            "number_of_replicas" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

Reindex from old index to new one, specify type only if you desire:

```
POST /_reindex?slices=5
{
    "size": 100000,
    "source": { "index": "my_old_index" },
    "dest": { "index": "my_new_index", "type": "my_type" }
}
```

Comment: I got an issue Search rejected due to missing shards [[my_index][0]]. Consider using `allow_partial_search_results` setting to bypass this error.", how can I skip that?

Answer (score 2):

Updated syntax to avoid some deprecation warnings in Elasticsearch 6+

per
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/indices-templates.html

```
PUT /_template/index_defaults 
{
  "index_patterns": ["*"],
  "order" : 0,
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that specifying the number of shards is a static operation and should be done when creating an index. But, any change after the index is created will require complete reindexing again which will take time.

To create the number of shards when creating an index use this command.

`curl -XPUT ‘localhost:9200/my_sample_index?pretty’ -H ‘Content-Type: application/json’ -d’
{
  “settings:”{
    “number_of_shards”:2,
        “number_of_replicas”:0
  }
}`

you don't have to to run this on all the nodes. run them on any one node. All the nodes communicate with each other about the change to the elastic index.